# How can I create a LOV where the user can select as many options as they want (like a series of checkboxes and select all that apply)?

Tags: teamcenter, teamcenter-soa

How can I create a list of values (LOV) where the user can select as many options as they want (like a series of checkboxes and select all that apply)? I am only away of being able to select one option as opposed to selecting many, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The property you will attach the LOV to will need to be an array. Then in TC you can multi-select more than one value of the LOV."

Source: https://community.sw.siemens.com/s/question/0D54O00007DC6yWSAT/how-can-i-create-a-lov-where-the-user-can-select-as-many-options-as-they-want-like-a-series-of-checkboxes-and-select-all-that-apply